# Single field in django modelform

Tags: django, modelform

I want to show only one field of a model though a modelform, I tried just putting that field in the fields list, but it crashes like this http://i1.imageban.ru/out/2011/03/18/f5b78d2a2351a1adeec3c8d2f5452859.png , if I add any other field it works fine, someone knows why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us some code, but looks like you did not put fields as a list e.g. you did

```
fields = my_field_name
```

instead you need to do this

```
field = (my_field_name,)
```